# Monitor is getting list in Advanced Display setting on my Dell Laptop but not able to get display on it

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, external-display

Problem: Not able to see anything on connected Monitor with My Laptop.

I have connected BenQ G920HD Monitor which is having DVI interface with my Dell Latitude 5400 which is having HDMI Interface So there is a [HDMI to DVI Adapter](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00I7T7IV0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with [HDMI to HDMI cable](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00NHFQUIG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) I am using.

On Display Settings When I click on Detect button it is saying that "Didn't detect another Display." but when I go to Advanced Display Settings and I expand the **Choose Display** Drop down it is showing me another BenQ G920HD Display.

[image: Attached Image is showing my Advanced Display settings Window there you can see connected display.]

Comment: How about regular display settings?

Comment: In Display Settings Also I can see 2nd display but when I click on Detect button, it is saying that "Didn't detect another Display."

Comment: Have you used adapter+cable with another monitor? On another computer?

Comment: Well, you can already see the 2nd display, there's no 3rd one to detect. What are you trying to achieve that's not possible with regular Display Settings?

Comment: I tried and it is working very smoothly with other Asus X540UA-DM995T Laptop without any other efforts.

Comment: @gronostaj I want to connect 1 monitor only with my laptop, it is listing in that drop down but I cant see anything on Monitor. I can see display only on my laptop screen.